# Dropdown options are displayed in the wrong place. (IE only)

Tags: lookup-column

I am using SP2010. In one of the lists I have several lookup fields as dropdowns in the forms, and I have a weird issue:
3 of 4 dropdowns, which are rendered as input (>20 items) are opened in a wrong location after opening one of the dropdowns in the form. Maning that after I opened dropdown#1 options, and then opened dropdown#2 options - dropdown#2's options will open under dropdown#1 field. See example below.

Few more important details:

1. It happens in IE9, but Chrome works fine.
2. Other dropdown which is rendered as select, works fine.
3. As i said, this mishmash happens only after one of the 3 dropdowns was opened.

Example, notice Site & Campus fields. Both lookups with >20 items hence rendered as inputs.

Normally opens 'Campus':

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJxoP.png]

Mislocation of 'Campus' options under 'Site' field:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QNTn.png]

Comment: You appear to have a third party Cascading Lookup installed, is that right? If so, you'll need to consult the provider for a resolution.

Comment: Actually no, it happens even in the 'natural' form if I neutralize all external code.

Comment: This rendering logic is baked into the lookup field for IE and +20 items. I once wrote a ControlAdapter that would bypass this. If you're interested drop me a note. Are you using a modified master page or injecting custom script ?

Comment: Thanks, do you have any solution based on JS. I'm not so familiar with C# customizations. I am currently working with injected JS.

Comment: @user2633360, to work around this issue I've created autocomplete lookup (pure js + jQuery). If you are interested, I'll assist you tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to convert the "complex dropdown" (20+ options in IE only) to a "simple dropdown", SPServices has a function called SPComplexToSimpleDropdown which will do it for you.
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown

Answer (score 1):

It happens only in IE because the IE render the dropdowns with 20+ items as if it is auto complete and then it causes many problems because it is uncontrollable.

I was having the same issue. After trying a lot of solution, I followed this link http://sharepointegg.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/fixing-sharepoint-2010-lookup-drop-down.html

The code snippet works like charm, you just have to add it to the page and specify the drop downs you need to fix.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for compiled code to resolve this issue - Simply add 2 lines of CSS to fix this.

```
select
{
    position: inherit !important;
    display: block;
}
```

From here [CSS solution to the lookup column drop down list select area positioning](http://planet-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/sharepoint-lookup-column-dropown-list_31.html)